# How to sort data by column in descending order in R

Tags: r

I've looked and looked and the answer either does not work for me, or it's far too complex and unnecessary.

I have data, it can be any data, here is an example

```
chickens <- read.table(textConnection("
feathers beaks
2   3
6   4
1   5
2   4
4   5
10  11                               
9   8
12  11
7   9
1   4
5   9
"), header = TRUE)
```

I need to, very simply, sort the data for the 1st column in descending order. It's pretty straightforward, but I have found two things below that both do not work and give me an error which says:

> "Error in order(var) : Object 'var' not found.

They are:

```
chickens <- chickens[order(-feathers),]
```

and

```
chickens <- chickens[sort(-feathers),]
```

I'm not sure what I'm not doing, I can get it to work if I put the `df` name in front of the `varname`, but that won't work if I put an minus sign in front of the `varname` to imply descending sort.

I'd like to do this as simply as possible, i.e. no boolean logic variables, nothing like that. Something akin to `SPSS`'s

`SORT BY varname (D)`

The answer is probably right in front of me, I apologize for the basic question.

Thank you!

Comment: I should be a good sport and mention that this is duplicate to so many things, including 10k+ reputation answers like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-columns-in-r/6871968#6871968

Comment: Take the whiz if you like, but the answers in the link are not a simple, clean, single line. And the first one, the square brackets, the with, the negative in front of the varname. I wanted to avoid all of that. Thank you for the answer below.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use dataframe name as prefix

```
chickens[order(chickens$feathers),]
```

To change the order, the function has `decreasing` argument

```
chickens[order(chickens$feathers, decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: ...or wrap the whole expression in `with()`, or use any of the other methods for referring to a column of a data frame via `[` or `[[`.

Comment: Or instead of `decreasing`, you can just put a `-` sign in front: `chickens[order(-chickens$feathers),] `

Answer (score 4):

The syntax in base R, needs to use dataframe name as a prefix as @dmi3kno has shown. Or you can also use `with` to avoid using dataframe name and `$` all the time as mentioned by @joran.

However, you can also do this with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(chickens)[order(-feathers)]
#Also
#setDT(chickens)[order(feathers, decreasing = TRUE)]

#    feathers beaks
# 1:       12    11
# 2:       10    11
# 3:        9     8
# 4:        7     9
# 5:        6     4
# 6:        5     9
# 7:        4     5
# 8:        2     3
# 9:        2     4
#10:        1     5
#11:        1     4
```

and `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
chickens %>% arrange(desc(feathers))
```