# R programming, how do I sort data frame by string column in descending order?

Tags: r

```
temp <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c("ba", "ab", "cc"))
temp
  x y
1 1 ba
2 2 ab
3 3 cc
```

and I want to order by ascending x and descending y, but it doesn't work even I convert y from factor to string.

```
tt <- temp[order(-as.character(y)), ]
```

> Error in -as.character(y) : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51502077/8245406) is related, though not exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `decreasing = TRUE`

```
temp[order(as.character(temp$y), decreasing = TRUE),]
```

Comment: sorry, I meant, I want to order by ascending x and descending y. like temp[order(x, -as.character(y)), ]

Comment: @sunflower In that case, it would give the order of iinput example.  Check `temp %>% arrange(x, desc(as.character(y)))` (from Lennyy's solution)

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`:

```
temp %>% 
  arrange(desc(y))
```